# Cannot retrieve values from class swift

Tags: swift, data-retrieval

I cannot retrieve values which have previously been set in a class.

All works fine when I print out that values in `addJourneyStart` but when i try to print out the same values in the `addJourneyEnd` it doesn't print anything!

```
private var trip = Journey()

//Adds the journey starting location
func addJourneyStart(startTime: Int64, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    trip.uuid = UUID().uuidString
    trip.startTime = startTime
    trip.startLat = latitude
    trip.startLong = longitude
    print("Save!! DOA 2 \((trip.uuid,trip.startTime, trip.startLat,trip.startLong)) UUID IS \(getJourneyUUID())")

}

//Adds the journey ending location
func addJourneyEnd( endTime: Int64, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, distance: Double) {
    trip.endTime = endTime
    trip.endLat = latitude
    trip.endLong = longitude
    trip.distance = distance
    print("Save!! Add End \((trip.startTime, trip.startLat,trip.startLong)) UUID IS \(getJourneyUUID())")
    save()
}
```

Here is the class I'm storing the values to

```
import Foundation

class Journey {

    var id: Int? = nil
    var uuid: String = ""
    var distance: Double = 0.0
    var endLat: Double = 0.0
    var endLong: Double = 0.0
    var endTime: Int64 = 0
    var startLat: Double = 0.0
    var startLong: Double = 0.0
    var startTime: Int64 = 0
    var travelTime: Int64 = 0
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. Where are you calling these methods? In what scope are they declared?

Comment: Where are you calling these methods?

Comment: You need to include the code showing how these functions are called. The issue is how / where you are using them

Comment: Side note: this data model is poorly designed, and it'll hurt you if you don't fix it soon. A journey with a nil id, empty string uuid, 0 distance, 0 lat, 0 long, etc. is nonsense, but it's a valid value that `Journey` objects can have, and is how they all start out. Instead, you should use more appropriate types (e.g. `uuid: UUID`, `endLocation: CLLocation2D`, `endTime: Date`, `travelTime: TimeInterval`), and create an initializer that sets them all immediately, to valid values. This way, all `Journey` objects are always in a valid state, and don't suffer from this two-stage initialization.